# fullcalendar click on date is not working

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

In fullcalender when I click on the date. the date is not selecting for the first time when I click again the date get selected

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
  header: {
    left: 'prev,next today',
    center: 'title',
    right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
  },
  selectable: true,
  events: function(){

        title: 'Test1',
        start: new Date(2017, 4, 20),
        tip: 'Personal tip 1'
    },
    title: 'Test2',
    start: new Date(2017, 4, 21),
    tip: 'Personal tip 2'
  }
});
```

Comment: Can you post your HTML code aswell

Comment: `<div id="calendar"></div>` i just calling this div only @JulianSchmuckli

Answer (score 0):

I have some comment for your example.

**First:**
I dont know how is `new Date(2017, 4, 20)` code works for you, because from your example I could not figure out. I suggest you to add more details.

**Second:**
If you want to add your events a new variable (as in your example *tip*) then you should check how to do it, in the official [doc](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_rendering/eventRender/).

**Third:** `events` variable of fullcalendar can get a function, but not that way as in your example. Check the official [doc](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/events_function/).

**Fourth:** I have to define what happen if an event is clicked. Check official [doc](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/mouse/eventClick/).

This is an [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tbzs8cpz/) example, what is works for me with your code.

Comment: thank you for your reply @LakiGeri I solved the problem. Problem is version I used 3.0.2 in latest version I had this problem and then I changed to 3.0.1 now its working fine

Answer (score 0):

```
dayClick: function(date, jsEvent, view) {

alert('Clicked on: ' + date.format());

alert('Coordinates: ' + jsEvent.pageX + ',' + jsEvent.pageY);

alert('Current view: ' + view.name);

// change the day's background color just for fun
$(this).css('background-color', 'red');
```

}

Please check on [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/np94fqyc/)